# Moving a Piece on an 64-square Grid (8 x 8) from Its Original Square to an Adjacent Square

Tags: visual

There is a 64-square grid (8 x 8 squares).  There is a piece that can start in any square.  It can only move 3 spaces in a straight line and then move 1 space to the right or the left (the type of L-movement a knight could make on a Chess board but one space farther than a knight before turning).  Can this piece end up in a square that is adjacent to its original square?

I think not, but I am not 100% sure.  And if it can't, I am having trouble proving this mathematically.  Is it just that if it only can move 3 spaces in a straight line, and the board is 8 squares long, you will eventually end up diagonally from the original square?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> NO

Because

> In one step it always goes to the same color of its originating position. As in checkerboard the adjacent cells have different color then it's impossible.